# Export Azure SQL Database to XML File

Tags: sql-server, xml, azure

I have searched Google and this site for about 2 hours trying to gather how to do this and no luck on a way that fits/ I understand. As the title says, I need to export table data to an XML file. I have an Azure SQL database with table data.

Table name: District

Table Columns: Id, name, organizationType, address, etc.

I need to take this data and create a XML file that I can save so that it can be given to others.

I have tried using:

```
SELECT * 
FROM dbo.District
FOR XML PATH('districtEntry'), ROOT('leaID')
```

It gives me the data in XML format, but I don't see a way to save it.

Also, there are some functions I need to be able to perform with the data:

> Program should have these options:
>
> 1) Export all data.
>
> 2) Export all rows created or updated since a specified date.
>
> Files should be named in format ENTITY.DATE.XML, as in
>   DISTRICT.20150521.XML (use date in YYYYMMDD format).

This leads me to believe I need to write code other than SQL since a requirement would be to query the table for certain data elements as well.

I was wondering if I would need to download any Database Server Data Tools, write code, and if so, in what language, etc. The XML file creation would need to be automated I believe after every update of the table or after a query.

I am very confused and in need of guidance as I now have almost given up hope. Please let me know if I need to clarify anything. Thank you.

P.S. I would have given pictures but I do not have enough reputation to supply them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would imagine you're looking to write a program in VB.NET or C#, using ADO.NET in either case.  Here's an MSDN article with a complete sample of how to connect to and query SQL Azure:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/ee336243.aspx

The example shows how to write the output to the `Console`, but you could also write the output similarly using something like a `StreamWriter` to write it to a file.

You could also create a `sqlcmd` script to do this, following the guidelines here to connect using `sqlcmd`:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/ee336280.aspx

Alternatively, if this is a process that does not need to be automated or repeated frequently, you could do it using SSMS:

http://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/sql-database-manage-azure-ssms/

Running your query through SSMS would produce an XML document, which could be saved using `File->Save As`

Comment: Yes, it does need to be automated. So let me get this straight. I would need to connect to Azure SQL Database using VB.Net program. Query my tables using said program, then use `StreamWriter` to export the code to an XML file? On your link I am seeing C# code but none for VB.NET. Maybe i'm not looking hard enough and if that's the case, i'm sorry.

Comment: The link only has a C# sample; you could achieve the same thing in VB.NET using the same ADO.NET classes though.  I'm not super familiar with VB.NET anymore (last time I did VB work was back on VB5...), so I can't help much with that, but the example doesn't appear to have anything too fancy C# wise in it, so it shouldn't be that hard to convert to VB.NET....

Comment: I don't really understand what it does after I run the code, it builds successfully, but then what to do next? Today, I have been playing around in VB and have connected to my azure subscription and database using SQL Sever Object Explorer. I also opened one of my tables and executed a query which resulted in an XML file. I just don't know how to automate it.

Comment: If you're not sure where to start with writing a VB program, you might be better off automating this process through some sqlcmd scripts that yo ucan just call from the commandline....

Comment: Thank you very much! After going through your posts for a couple of days I finally understand what needed to be done. I have written a VB console program which spits out an XML file for the given database, and then i will automate that process through the command line.